# Vivado simulation error: Iteration limit 10000 is reached

Tags: verilog, simulation

While I was trying to run the simulation in Vivado, I got:

> ERROR: Iteration limit 10000 is reached. Possible zero delay
> oscillation detected where simulation time can not advance. Please
> check your source code. Note that the iteration limit can be changed
> using switch -maxdeltaid. Time: 10 ns Iteration: 10000

I don't have any initial statement in my module being tested.

Could anybody point out where the problem could be?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module mulp(
input clk,
input rst,
input start,
input [4:0] mplier,  // -13
input [4:0] mplcant, // -9
output reg done,
output [9:0] product
);

parameter N = 6;
parameter Idle = 2'b00;
parameter Load = 2'b01;
parameter Oper = 2'b10;
parameter Finish = 2'b11;

reg done_r;
reg [N-1:0] A, A_r, B, B_r;
reg [1:0] state, state_r;
reg [2:0] count, count_r; 

wire [N-2:0] C, C_comp;
reg [N-2:0] C_r;
   
assign C = mplcant; assign C_comp = {~C + 1};
assign product = {A_r[N-2:0], B_r[N-2:0]};

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        state_r <= Idle;
        count_r <= 0;
        done_r <= 0;
        A_r <= 0;
        B_r <= 0;
    end else begin
        state_r <= state;
        count_r <= count;
        done_r <= done;
        A_r <= A;
        B_r <= B;
    end // if
end // always

always @(*) begin
    state = state_r;
    count = count_r - 1; // count: 6
    done = done_r;
    A = A_r;
    B = B_r;
    
    case (state) 
        Idle: begin
            if (start) begin
                state <= Load;
            end // if
        end
        Load: begin
            A = 0; B = {mplier, 1'b0}; count = N; // start at 6
            state = Oper;
        end
        Oper: begin
            if (count == 0)
                state = Finish;
            else begin
                case (B[1:0])
                    2'b01: begin
                        // add C to A
                        A = A_r + {C[N-2], C[N-2:0]};
                        // shift A and B
                        A = {A_r[N-1], A_r[N-1:1]};
                        B = {A_r[0], B_r[N-1:1]};
                    end
                    2'b10: begin
                        A = A_r + {C_comp[N-2], C_comp[N-2:0]};
                        A = {A_r[N-1], A[N-1:1]};
                        B = {A_r[0], B_r[N-1:1]};
                    end
                    (2'b00 | 2'b11): begin
                        A = {A_r[N-1], A[N-1:1]};
                        B = {A_r[0], B_r[N-1:1]}; 
                    end
                    default: begin
                        state = Idle; done = 1'bx; // error
                    end
                endcase  
            end // else
        end // Oper
        Finish: begin
            done = 1; 
            state = Idle;
        end // Finish
        default: begin
            done = 1'bx;
            state = Idle;
        end 
    endcase
end // always

endmodule
```

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question, that would make it harder for future visitors to see if they have the same problem, and if the answer would help them too.

Comment: The attached code has many problems.

Comment: That may be, but removing the code removes the required context for the answer provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a combinational loop.  You are sampling and driving the `state` signal in the combinational `always` block.  Typically, you sample the registered state variable (`state_r` in your code) in an FSM.  Change:

```
case (state)
```

to:

```
case (state_r)
```

---

Unrelated, but you should use all **blocking** assignments in the combo block (not a mixture).  Change:

```
            state <= Load;
```

to:

```
            state = Load;
```